# Is it safe to use Python3.8.1 core py files that have been minified using PyMinifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, minify

I came across a Python source code "minifier" called `pyminifier`. Is it safe to run this against the Python3.8.1 core `.py` files?

Comment: Define "safe". What are you going to do with the minified files?

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe. I ran `python3.8 -m compileall .` to check if python produces different `.pyc` files, but I get many build errors. The command works on the original source. The utility broke the source code.